# Mongodb $within query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm attempting to make a geospatial query in `mongodb` using the `$within` operator. I have a collection entry that has a location field which holds:

```
location: {
  bounds: {
    south_west: { lat: XX.XXXXXX, lng: XX.XXXXX },
    north_east: { lat: XX.XXXXXX, lng: XX.XXXXX }
  },
  center: {
    lat: XX.XXXXXX,
    lng: XX.XXXXXX
  }
}
```

For my query, I'd like to get all places with a `location.center` that falls within the bounds of the `google.maps` object. I have something like this:

```
query = {}

var southWest = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
southWest = [southWest.lat(), southWest.lng()];

var northEast = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
northEast = [northEast.lat(), northEast.lng()];

query["location.center"] = { $within: { $box: [southWest, northEast] } }
```

But I consistently get

```
Exception from Meteor.flush: Error: Unrecognized key in selector: $within
at Error (<anonymous>)
at Function.LocalCollection._exprForConstraint (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/selector.js?2373a18a9a4640513e41d7850f17f62f76b7c589:559:11)
at Function.LocalCollection._exprForOperatorTest (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/selector.js?2373a18a9a4640513e41d7850f17f62f76b7c589:468:36)
at Function.LocalCollection._exprForKeypathPredicate (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/selector.js?2373a18a9a4640513e41d7850f17f62f76b7c589:387:34)
at Function.LocalCollection._exprForSelector (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/selector.js?2373a18a9a4640513e41d7850f17f62f76b7c589:307:36)
at Function.LocalCollection._compileSelector (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/selector.js?2373a18a9a4640513e41d7850f17f62f76b7c589:284:24)
at new LocalCollection.Cursor (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js?7f5131f0f3d86c8269a6e6db0e2467e28eff6422:71:39)
at LocalCollection.find (http://localhost:3000/packages/minimongo/minimongo.js?7f5131f0f3d86c8269a6e6db0e2467e28eff6422:57:10)
at _.extend.find (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js?3ef9efcb8726ddf54f58384b2d8f226aaec8fd53:155:34)
at Template.feed.feed_items (http://localhost:3000/client/modules/js/feed.js?5ed30ddbd861944b636dbe03c13cc80421258a5b:129:17)
```

And I'm unsure how to proceed. With a simple JSON.stringify(query) I've noticed that the query is coming out like

```
{"location.center":{"$within":{"$box":[[39.93623526127148,-75.63687337060549],[39.984129247435064,-75.57438862939455]]}}}
```

Is there anyway I can prevent the quotes from being wrapped around the `$within` and `$box` selectors? I believe that's where my exception is being thrown from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quotes aren't the problem, that's just valid JSON. The problem is that minimongo doesn't implement $within yet. Matt Debergalis [commented on Minimongo's incomplete state](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-core/o2w4b33m-Co) (23 oct 2012):

> The recent traffic on meteor-talk reminds me that minimongo comes with 
>   a healthy wish list of improvements and extensions.
>
> [...]
>
> - $near, $within, and $maxDistance.

You may have better luck executing this in the server where you have "real" mongodb access, but I'm not sure how that works if the client store doesn't have the same functionality.

[Minimongo's source code is available](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/minimongo). Perhaps you should try your hand at implementing this selector yourself and sending a pull request? :)

Comment: started at it before you even made your first edit ;) thanks for the heads up about minimongo

Comment: Looks like there's already a pull request for it: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/443

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old question but just in case anyone revisits this you can use this to do a query on minimongo:

```
locations.find(
    { "location.lng" : {
        "$gt" : bottomLeftLng,
        "$lt":  topRightLng  
      },
      "location.lat": {
        "$gt" : bottomLeftLat,
        "$lt": topRightLat
      }
   }
)
```